# AWS virtual private cloud: private subnet and ip ranges

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, subnet, vpc

Can I use "175.16.0.0/16", for VPC private range on AWS cloud! I have read the amazon white papers guide lines, not found restrictions but some colleagues who dealt with the matter of vpc creation tend to favour staying away from that range!

Comment: Why are you wanting to use this range?

Answer (score 0):

They're probably saying that because there are reserved IP ranges for use on private networks. These addresses are not routable from the Internet.

The IP range you specified is not one of them.

You can read more about this in [Private network - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks John, I had an issue with the health of the NLB, this my colleague proposed that there is an issue with the ip block, I think there is with that block, I do think that the major point with the NLB issue is that there was no service listening on that port to start with.